# Printer scaling is randomly off

Tags: scaling

I built a custom 3D printer using a BTT SKR Mini e3 v1.2 and use Pronterface to run my prints.

The problem I've been experiencing with it is from time to time the printer will attempt to print with a scale much bigger than what I wanted (roughly twice as big). I test with the same slicer file, and on different attempts it will print with different scales. It seems that the stepper motors run twice as fast and that is what is causing the change in scale. Has anyone had this happened?

Comment: Is it 2.54 times larger, as if something was using centimetres instead of inches?

Comment: Could be number of microsteps being programmed inconsistently...?

Comment: How could I check if the microsteps are programmed inconsistanty? Isn't there one place for it? I suspect the problem is in the slicer or pronterface.